# Anime about a girl, who becomes an adult by using magic and starts modeling

Tags: fancy-lala

I remember an anime I watched on Indian television 8 years ago or maybe more. The points I remember are:

- The girl gets some soft toys from a toy store. (She doesn't buy them but they follow her)
- One soft toy was some kind of a cute dinosaur
- The toys have magical powers. They give a notebook and pen to the girl
- She somehow becomes an adult by using these magical items, and she can repeat this to turn back to normal
- In her adult form, she helps a lady, who helps her to become a model
- One day she loses her powers and can't turn into her adult form. The modelling company ends up in trouble because their model disappears
- Her adult self has a short hairstyle

Some doubtful points, which might not be completely accurate:

- Her hair color changes between forms. Maybe red and blue
- The modeling company she works in also has an employee that is a relative to her (mother or big sister)

Comment: thank you fr providing this answer..:D i was trying to remembr the name for like 2 years..:D

Comment: Downvote reason for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be [**Fancy Lala**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fancy_Lala)

> One day, nine-year-old girl Miho Shinohara is given two stuffed dinosaurs by a stranger. The stuffed dinosaurs come to life and present her with a magic sketchbook and pen. Within limits, and subject to varying degrees of control, she can draw in the sketchbook and bring the drawings to life. Miho can also transform into a teenage girl, whom she names Fancy Lala. Fancy Lala is scouted by Yumi Haneishi, the president of the talent agency Lyrical Productions, and begins the long road to stardom.

[image]